# Calling a Jenkinsfile from a remote repo into build pipeline

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I would like to pull a source controlled version of a Declarative Jenkinsfile into a multibranch jenkins job.

For example, I have 20 multibranch build job each building an application and deploying, each build job will have a static jenkinsfile that point to, pull and use a version controlled jenkinsfile.

This would reduce the need to make changes across all repositories when making changes

(we do use shared libraries where relevant)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't really know multibranch pipelines, but I think I miss something? Why not just putting the jenkinsfile as pipeline.groovy in the shared library and use it with @Library('xxx')_
pipelinename {..

Answer (score 0):

You can define the whole pipeline as a global variable within a Shared Library, then you can use a single step in your Jenkinsfile, as explained [here](https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/10/02/pipeline-templates-with-shared-libraries/).
In that way you are able to update the content of the pipeline, without updating each Jenkinsfile accross all your repositories.